Creating timeseries in R with a break
I am completely new to the ts() function in base R.
I can't find information on whether the following is possible,
for
dat <- ts(x, start = c(1950, 1), end = c(2100, 12), frequency = 12)
is it possible to exclude all elements from 2015 through 2046?
I have found a way to create the timeseries and set those particular values to NA, but this is not what I'm looking for.

You can use the zoo package here.
Use the window and time functions to extract what you want and then use zoo::zoo to create the irregular time series.
ts1 <- c(time(window(dat, end=2014)), 
         time(window(dat, start=2047)))
ts2 <- zoo::zoo(x, ts1)


na.omit(as.zoo(dat)) would also work if the only NA's are the ones in the unwanted months.
